# How to do address autocomplete right?

Tags: forms, google, autocomplete, autofill

I'm working on a webshop that wants to introduct automatic address completion using googles Place Automcomplete API. My main focus is usability and getting it right isn't exactly easy. My main problems are:

- the browsers autofill-function overlays most "classic" approaches that just show googles suggestions right below the input field. Disabling autofill for the field would be the easiest approach, but I don't want that either. Users that have the right address in their autofill should be able to use it, but those who don't should be able to use Googles suggestions. From a UI standpoint I dont want anything to overlay anything - so that's my first problem: Where/How to display Googles suggestions? I was thinking about putting it into a speech bubble above the field, but users aren't used to that.
- I don't want Googles suggestions to be as random as they are. If a user starts typing their street name, chances are that google suggests streets from all over the world but not the one they are looking for. It's possible to feed Google a country and a zip-code, but asking for those two is, again, something user's aren't used to. Asking for those details via some sort of wizard comes to mind, but even that's not something I'm used to seeing for address forms.

So, it all comes down to making the thing as usable as possible. I'm looking for completely different approaches as well, if anyone of you has a better idea or knows a shop that does it in another way.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Your question is a little too broad and I feel your question would get better answers if you clearly laid out a specific problem rather than asking us to brainstorm for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is more technical question than UX.
First you need to draw a bold line between technical implementation (Google maps API) and desired UX (suggest addresses nicely)

When you do that, thing will become easy the same moment.
Forkflow for you:
1. Design autocomplete
2. Consult to devs
3A. If this is idea is possible to implement - great success
3B. If it is impossible to implement. It is no longer UX problem. Design is right, but technology is not up to date. Go to step 1 :)

---

**1.** There is no technical way to command browser to "show or hide native autocomplete". Deal with it. therefore you can not nicely mix native automplete results with your suggestions in one list.
Your only option is to make your custom autocomplete and ask browser to completely disable native autocomplete, browser may ignore it under some circumstances.

Feel the pain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off

---

**2.** May I answer with another question

> Why would user start typing from street?

Because he or she lives in the same city as a shop and therefore think that there is no need to enter zipcode or country name.

> Why would site suggest me a street in another country if I live near
>   to the shop?

Because the developer was not wise enought :)
Simple solution to this is to assume that this street or house is in the same city.